# Does China have a "space coast"? Will it?

Tags: launch-site, china

I noticed that the Chinese GEO communications satellite [Apstar 6C](https://spaceflight101.com/events/long-march-3b-apstar-6c/) was launched from the [Xichang Satellite Launch Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xichang_Satellite_Launch_Center) in Sichuan, China. Saying this is far inland would be an understatement.

**Question:** Does China have a "space coast" launch area (analogous to [Cape Canaveral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral) or [Sriharikota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sriharikota)), current or planned?

One of the advantages of launching from a coast is that things fall into the ocean, where there are significantly fewer people for it to fall on.

Screen shot from Google Maps:

[image]

Comment: Currently working on getting google maps to display in English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_space_program#Monitoring_and_control_centers

> The PRC operates 4 satellite launch centers:
>
> Jiuquan Satellite Launch Center (JSLC)
>
> Xichang Satellite Launch Center (XSLC)
>
> Taiyuan Satellite Launch Center (TSLC)
>
> [Wenchang Satellite Launch Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wenchang_Satellite_Launch_Center) (WSLC)

Wenchang is a coastal/island facility roughly midway between Vietnam and the Philippines, at around 19 degrees N latitude.  The others are inland.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wenchang_Satellite_Launch_Center):

> It (Wenchang) is a former sub-orbital test center. It is China's fourth and southernmost space vehicle launch facility (spaceport). It has been specially selected for its low latitude, which is only 19 degrees north of the equator, **which will allow for a substantial increase in payload, necessary for the future manned program, space station and deep space exploration program. Furthermore, it is capable of launching the new heavy-lift Long March 5 booster.** (emphasis added)

Comment: `+1` I hope you don't mind the edit; that quote really addresses my concerns.

Comment: There's another bit you may also find relevant:  the facility can handle barges, which increases the size of booster it can work with (similar to how SpaceX will be barging around bits of BFR/BFS).  I didn't think that helped with the question at hand when I read it, but maybe you will.